# Nginx block access to php files

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting, fastcgi

I've created a simple php file to display info fetched from my MYSQL database. Right after that i use a rewrite rule in Nginx to make the link seo friendly and to mask the .php file that fetches it.

Ex: `http://localhost/myfile.php?seo=how-to-install-linux`
After rewrite rule the i can access it like:

```
http://localhost/how-to-install-linux
```

My rewrite rules are:

```
location / {
rewrite ^/([a-zA-Z0-9_$\-]+)$ /myfile.php?seo=$1 last;
rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent; <- just to block trailing slash
}
```

My problem is that i also want to block any direct access to my php file and i want only the seo friendly url to work.

```
location = /myfile.php {
deny all;
}
```

This rule blocks complete access to my php file, including through seo friendy url.
Is there a way to make it work for the seo friendly version using NGINX?
My other settings are:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
try_files $uri =404;
include fcgi.conf;
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/ajenti-v-php7.0-fcgi-drnou-php7.0-fcgi-0.sock;

}
```

I only use Nginx, no Apache installed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `internal` directive to prevent a location from being accessed directly. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#internal) for details.

For example:

```
location = /myfile.php {
    internal;
    include fcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/ajenti-v-php7.0-fcgi-drnou-php7.0-fcgi-0.sock;
}
```

Comment: It works ! Thanks man. I've searched on Google with basic search terms but haven't found nothing useful. Again, thanks !