# Nginx rewrite to prevent PHP file direct access

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I'm trying to setup some rewrites so that
(1) .com/images/* will load naturally
(2) .com/* will be rewritten to .com/loader.php?control=*
However the code below works perfectly except it will execute .com/config.php instead of rewriting it to .com/loader.php?control=config.php

How can I prevent my rewrite being overridden? I only want .php files to be executed if it's loader.php or in the images folder. (Been trying for hours)

```
server {
        listen       80;
        root /mnt/web/test_com/public_html;
        server_name test.com;
        index  index.html index.php index.htm;
        location ~ .php(.*)$ {
                fastcgi_pass  unix:/tmp/php-70-cgi.sock;
                fastcgi_index  index.php;
                fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $DOCUMENT_ROOT$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $2;
                include fcgi.conf;
        }
        location / {
                 rewrite ^/(.*)$ /loader.php?control=$1 last;
        }
        location /images/ {
        }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the try_files directive

> Like the return and rewrite directives, the try_files directive is placed in a server or location block. As parameters, it takes a list of one or more files and directories and a final URI

Read the whole blog-post written on the nginx blog here:
https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/

Comment: try_files seems to be a method of seeing whether a files exists or not and producing a default, this is not my goal.

As an example of what I want to do:
.com/whatever
will run an SQL search on "whatever" from a database
I only want /images/* to not be run through the SQL and just be run directly

The problem is if someone wants to search for "config.php", "config.php" will be executed instead of rewritten based on the code i published.

Comment: What you seem to want is to check if images exist in the /images/ catalog. Which I would do using try_files, everything else should be executed in the php file. Or am I way off?

Comment: Also, based on the configuration you posted in your question. Nothing will ever reach the ”location /images/” since everything will be picked up by ”location /” and the (.*) regex pattern in your rewrite.

Comment: I'm using that implementation now and I can directly open any file in the images folder with no problems. It appears that the more specific declaration, or perhaps the later listed takes priority.

Unfortunately I still haven't found a way to prevent execution of PHP files that should be hidden away by the rewrite. It was so much easier with Apache.

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47379091/nginx-block-access-to-php-files  You can use the internal directive to use a fastcgi config. So that direct access to the php files is not possible.